# Jquery Droppable Center Image in Div After Drop Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey there,i'm creating a simple inventory using jQuery droppable. For now, it's like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $( ".weapon, .helmet" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid", cursor: "move" });
 $( "#weapon_spot" ).droppable({accept: ".weapon"});
 $( "#helmet_spot" ).droppable({accept: ".helmet"});

 // make inventory slots droppable as well

 $( ".inv_slot" ).droppable({accept: ".weapon"});

});
```

I'm kinda new to JQuery and have some trouble setting an image to be aligned inside a certain div. Everything(.weapon, .helmet etc) is a div. Inside them, there can be images. The divs are 70x70 and the images are of that size as well.

The css is like :

```
.inv_slot, #weapon_spot, #helmet_spot {
    width: 70px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    height: 70px; 
    margin: 10px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and the image inside a div is like :

```
<div class='inv_slot'>
    <img class='weapon' src= "..." />
</div>
```

My problem is that when i drop an image to another div, it's not aligned in the center of the div, it's not locked and it can be moved inside it. It seems that i can use Drag.Move somehow to do that, but i can't find some good resource explaining that. Could you please help ? :)

EDIT : I have created a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/kzuRn/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a drop callback to the droppables and apply the style changes necessary. Because right now the item is still positioned absolutely it will not recognize your center css.

**Something like this: *WRONG* (see below)**

```
drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $(this).css({position: 'static'})
}
```

---

I updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzuRn/3/). I was wrong before. `this` is the droppable, and `ui.draggable` is the draggable.

```
drop: function(ev, ui) {
    $(this).append(ui.draggable.css('position','static'))
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the effect i get out of that is that when i drop the draggable item(the image) to the droppable, the draggable div is moved slightly upwards. However, the image inside the div is still moving. I've added some more code so that it's easier for you to take a look. Thanx for any help :)

Comment: @SpyrosP - since you have a text-align center on the parent just setting the position back to static should work.

Comment: still it's not working. Please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/kzuRn/2/ . Consider the image a weapon and try to drag it to the weapon box to see the effect.